# How to convert integer to char

Tags: type-conversion, character, julia

I have a bunch of integers ns where 0 <= n <= 9 for all n in ns. I need to save them as characters or strings. I used @time to compare memory usage and I got this:

```
julia> @time a = "a"
  0.000010 seconds (84 allocations: 6.436 KiB)
"a"

julia> @time a = 'a'
  0.000004 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

1. Why such a huge difference?

I chose to convert the integers into characters, but I don't understand what's the proper way to do it. When I do `Char(1)` in the REPL I get `'\x01': ASCII/Unicode U+0001 (category Cc: Other, control)` and if I try to print it I get this symbol:  .

Instead when I do `'1'` in the REPL I get `'1': ASCII/Unicode U+0031 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)` and if I print it I get `1`. This is the behavior I want.

2. How to achieve it?

I thought about creating a dictionary to assign to each integer its corresponding character, but I am pretty sure that's not the way to go ...

Comment: Use `Char(n + '0')`. This will add the ASCII offset of the `0` digit and fix the rest of the digits too.

Comment: Timing with `@time` is a bit problematic, especially for very small operations. Try to use `@btime` or `@benchmark` from BenchmarkTools.jl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Char(n + '0')`. This will add the ASCII offset of the `0` digit and fix the rest of the digits too. For example:

```
julia> a = 5
5

julia> Char(a+'0')
'5': ASCII/Unicode U+0035 (category Nd: Number, decimal digit)
```

Also note, timing with `@time` is a bit problematic, especially for very small operations. It is better to use `@btime` or `@benchmark` from BenchmarkTools.jl .

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like:

```bash
julia> bunch_of_integers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

julia> String(map(x->x+'0', bunch_of_integers))
"12345"
```

or something like:

```bash
julia> map(Char, bunch_of_integers.+'0')
5-element Array{Char,1}:
 '1'
 '2'
 '3'
 '4'
 '5'
```

Comment: using map seems to be overkill! But when I first tried `bunch_of_integers.+'0'` it returned `Array{Int64,1}: [49,50,51,52,53] ` Maybe my REPL was overflown (or is buggy)...